# Is it safe to store database credentials as plain text in the configuration file?

Tags: databases, configuration, debian

Some services like `ejabberd`, `nginx` for authenticating using a database, and `dovecot` requires providing the database password as plain text in the configuration file. Is it safe to store MariaDB password as plain text provided that processes are isolated in chroots or for instance containers, mandatory access control is present on the system and permissions on the configuration files are properly set?

I need to protect the database user password from unauthorized processes running on the system in case of any vulnerabilities in the services.

I am the only user of the Debian 12 server which I use mostly for stuff like hosting my e-mail, PHP code in the Gitea repository. This server has regularly applied security updates.

Example configuration file:

```
...
#   You can connect to UNIX sockets by using host: host=/var/run/mysql.sock                                                                                                               
#   Note that currently you can't use spaces in parameters.                                                                                                                               
#                                                                                                                                                                                         
# sqlite:                                                                                                                                                                                 
#   The path to the database file.                                                                                                                                                        
#                                                                                                                                                                                         
# Examples:                                                                                                                                                                               
#   connect = host=192.168.1.1 dbname=users                                                                                                                                               
#   connect = host=sql.example.com dbname=virtual user=virtual password=blarg                                                                                                             
#   connect = /etc/dovecot/authdb.sqlite                                                                                                                                                  
#                                                                                                                                                                                         
connect = host=/var/run/postgresql/ dbname=mail user=mailreader                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                          
# Default password scheme.                                                                                                                                                                
#                                                                                                                                                                                         
# List of supported schemes is in                                                                                                                                                         
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes                                                                                                                                 
#                                                                                                                                                                                         
default_pass_scheme = SHA512                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                          
# passdb query to retrieve the password. It can return fields:                                                                                                                            
#   password - The user's password. This field must be returned.                                                                                                                          
#   user - user@domain from the database. Needed with case-insensitive lookups.
#   username and domain - An alternative way to represent the "user" field.
#
# The "user" field is often necessary with case-insensitive lookups to avoid
# e.g. "name" and "nAme" logins creating two different mail directories. If
# your user and domain names are in separate fields, you can return "username"
# and "domain" fields instead of "user".
#
# The query can also return other fields which have a special meaning, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields
#
# Commonly used available substitutions (see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables
# for full list):
#   %u = entire user@domain
#   %n = user part of user@domain
#   %d = domain part of user@domain
...
```

Comment: Safe from what?

Comment: I modified question, take a look

Answer (score 1):

This question, like all that start with "Is it safe...", is a matter for threat modeling. Who are your potential attackers, what are the assets they're trying to compromise, what are the potential attacks, and how have you mitigated them? In particular, let's consider attacks that target the database, directly or indirectly, and see how much risk there is from each threat. I'm mostly going to assume network or internet attackers, since you say there are no other local users. This is not necessarily a comprehensive list, and not ever possible mitigation has necessarily been taken, but it should give you an idea how to go about thinking of these things yourself:

- Attacker uses SQL injection against the DB, via the webapp or any other DB client. Mitigated by using safe DB access patterns that don't enable SQLi. Doesn't require knowing the credentials; no additional risk.
- Attacker compromises your webserver, gaining code execution. In this scenario, they already have a live DB connection, or at least access to the credentials needed to create one, no matter how they're stored or passed to the server. Mitigated by regular patching and avoiding other vulnerabilities. No additional risk.
- Attacker accesses the database server directly. Mitigated by not having the server exposed to external interfaces, and by having strong credentials on the server. No additional risk.
- Attacker accesses the server via SSH (shell, SFTP, or other program). Mitigated by disallowing password authentication, or at least requiring a strong password, for SSH. Can be mitigated by making the credential file, DB file, DB server, and all DB clients run as separate users that the interactive (SSH-enabled) user doesn't have access to without supplying another password (though in practice I suspect you don't do this if you allow password access at all, the same password is probably used for `sudo`?). Unless you're willing to manually supply the DB credentials when starting DB clients, the credentials need to live on the server somewhere, so no additional risk from making them specifically an access-restricted file.
- Attacker accesses file backups from the server, including the credential file. Mitigated by restricting access to backups, and by encrypting backups. Mitigated by not having the server exposed, so the credentials are not immediately usable. Could be mitigated by making the credentials live in a file that isn't backed up (but you probably want to back up config files, so check if there's a way to store the credentials in a dedicated file and exclude that from backup, perhaps?) If the DB file itself is backed up, and that backup exposed, the credentials probably don't even matter (unless to enable decryption). At most a small increased risk.
- Attacker accesses full image of the volume or container, either through online storage, direct access to live copy, or compromising a backup. Mitigated by full volume encryption, trustworthy hosting, and not putting anything sensitive in things like Dockerfiles or Docker images. If the DB file is not included, mitigated due to still not having direct access to the DB. If the DB file is included, probably no additional risk unless a credential is needed to decrypt the DB. At most small increased risk.

There are probably some other threats; you know your environment better than anybody else. However, most likely, you'll be fine. You could be slightly more paranoid and pass the DB credentials to each DB client (e.g. webserver) when starting that DB client, without ever storing the credentials in the file system (make sure not to store them in e.g. shell logs by accident...), but the marginal security benefit there is minimal at best, and the inconvenience is considerable.

Answer (score 0):

Security is always about scenarios. Almost nothing is 100% safe from everything, but something may be secure enough in certain scenarios, under certain assumptions about the attacker's behavior and privileges.

At some point, your service will necessarily have the credentials in plaintext, at least in memory, unless [PKCS #11 or similar approaches with Hardware Security Modules (HSMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) are used.

So, the question becomes: can an attacker do something with a file that they can't do in memory?

An attacker might be able to read or edit the configuration file without having access to the runtime, volatile memory value. For example:

- a configuration file may be stored in an unencrypted volume. The owner of the storage platform may be able to read the password if it is stored in a file, but not if it is stored in memory (assuming they also don't have access to the virtual machines or containers hosting those services)
- different processes generally have distinct memory areas. An attacker might be able to read or write a file without being able to read or write portions of RAM belonging to the nginx process (which is only possible if you are that process or if you are root). This scenario should be mitigated by your claim that

> mandatory access control is present on the system and permissions on the configuration files are properly set